# Why is $A_n:=\{x_i : 1\leq i \leq n\}$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(x_n)_n\subset X$ a sequence
>   converging to $x \in X$ with $x_n \neq x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
>   Observe the sets $A_n:=\{x_i : 1\leq i \leq n\}$ for all $n\in
>  \mathbb{N}$.

Why is $A_n$ closed for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

**My Idea:**

I have to show that $X\backslash A_n$ has to be open. But isn't $X\backslash A_n=\{x\}$ and thus open?

Comment: In metric spaces, singleton are closed. Each of the sets you are considering are finite, hence finite union of singletons, hence closed.

Comment: Your space is metric, isn't it? Then each point is closed. And each $A_n$ is a finite union of closed sets. Therefore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any finite set $F$ is closed in a metric space $(X,d)$: let $x \notin F$.
Then we have finitely many distances $\{d(x,y): y \in F\}$ all of which are $>0$ (as $x \neq y$: $y \in F$ and $x \notin F$) and we can define $$r=\min\{d(x,y): y \in F\} >0$$

and then $B(x,r) \cap F = \emptyset$ ($z \in B(x,r) \implies d(x,z) < r$ and so $z \in F$ is impossible) and as we can do this for any $x \notin F$, $F$ is closed. We just use that a minimum of finitely many positive numbers is positive (and this shows where the same argument could fail for an infinite set).

So the sets $A_n$ are closed due to their obvious finiteness.

BTW, $X\setminus A_n$ does not equal $\{x\}$ (it will contain $x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}$ etc too which are potentially different, etc.) and the latter set would in general also not be open, so that's a wrong route to take.

Answer (score 0):

$X\setminus A_n$ is not necessarily equal to $\{x\}$.  All you can be sure of is that it *contains* $\{x\}$.

Consider for example if $X$ is the real line and $x_i=\frac1i$, which converges to $0$. Then a typical $A_i$ is $A_4=\{\frac14, \frac13, \frac12, 1\}$, and while $X\setminus A_4$ certainly includes $0$, it also includes a great many other points. In particular, it is not closed.